# TCL array: variable isn't array

Tags: arrays, tcl, associative-array

I looked at the other two topics on this and I'm still having issues. Here is part of the code that is causing the problem.

```
if {[llength $fileList] > 0} {
    set iter 1
    foreach f $fileList {
        puts "Sourcing $f..."
        if {[catch {source $f} rc]} {
            puts "file $f exists but unable to source.\nError message: $rc"
            return 1
        }
        array set dt [list $iter $dtList]
        puts $dt($iter)
        incr iter
    }
}
```

The line `array set dt [list $iter $dtList]` is causing the `can't read "dt(1)": variable isn't array` error to appear. Each file that I source creates a list named `dtList` and I am simply trying to loop through each file, set the `$dtList` list to another one (an array called `dt` here), and then later on concat these to create a full list.

I have also tried using `set dt($iter) $dtList` and the same error is appearing.

I feel like I am missing something extremely simple here but nothing I've tried is working.

Comment: You should already have a scalar variable named `dt` and now you are trying to create a variable array of that same name. That is why you are getting this error.

Comment: As @Dinesh explains, `dt` is already a non-array (scalar) variable at the time you execute `set dt($iter) $dtList`. You have to provide the context of the script, and it is not unlikely that `source $f` pollutes the environment this way. Without further details, it is hard to make any recommendations: rename `dt` to something non-colliding?  execute source in a throw-away environment (`apply`). If you don't trust the scripts in `$f`, you should `source` them in a (safe) child interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you try this:

```
if {[llength $fileList] > 0} {
    array set dt {}
    set iter 1
    foreach f $fileList {
        puts "Sourcing $f..."
        source $f
        array set dt [list $iter $dtList]
        puts $dt($iter)
        incr iter
    }
}
```

1. Pre-setting `dt` to an array means that you can easily find the place or places in the sourced files where something sets `dt` to a value. If `dt` is already an array, this will result in an error, pointing out the location for you.
2. (A little beside the point, but still worth mentioning) The `catch` construction seems misleading as no attempt is made to determine if the file actually exists. Usually, it's better to let initialization fail with an error than to report the error and continue.

But, if all you want to do is to collect a list of `$dtList` values, why not do so directly:

```
if {[llength $fileList] > 0} {
    set result [lmap f $fileList {
        puts "Sourcing $f..."
        source $f
        set dtList
    }]
}
```

Comment: I changed it to just loop over each list result of the file execution and append them to a master list. Much simpler, but I was so caught up with the array method I wanted to figure out why it was failing. I'm going to play around with your first suggestion. Thanks!